# State management in redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have an array named CATEGORIES and I want to return that using state in reducer but when I am consoling that state I am getting undefined.

```
import CATEGORIES  from '../../data/dummy_data';

const initialState = {
  availableItems: CATEGORIES
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log(state, 'hey there');
  return state;
}
```

and the console output  is `undefined hey there`

Comment: you did not name your reducer, that's the problem, i guess. you should do a named export and pass the same name for creating store

Comment: Everything is correct in the code that you've posted here.  I'm not able to reproduce your error.

Comment: Thanks, I found the error in my dummy_data I was exporting 2 arrays so I have to import {CATEGORIES } that was the problem.